# How to add an image next to the text in Google translate widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code, you can check it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mc1z2e7n/

as you can see it is a google translate widget with dropdown option with country flag option but the country flag is up and the text is above the country flag.

Now I need to have country image flag on the left side and the country text language name to be next to the flag on the right size, just like it is on this picture: https://ibb.co/xH3g6B6

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="ct-topbar">
 <div class="container">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline ct-topbar__list">
     <li class="ct-language">Language <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
       <ul class="list-unstyled ct-language__dropdown">
         <li><a href="#googtrans(en|en)" class="lang-en lang-select" data-lang="en"><img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.5.0/flags/4x3/af.svg" alt="USA"></a>USASSSSSSS</li>
         <li><a href="#googtrans(en|es)" class="lang-es lang-select" data-lang="es"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/google-translate/flag-mexico.png" alt="MEXICO"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#googtrans(en|fr)" class="lang-es lang-select" data-lang="fr"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/google-translate/flag-france.png" alt="FRANCE"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#googtrans(en|zh-CN)" class="lang-es lang-select" data-lang="zh-CN"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/google-translate/flag-china.png" alt="CHINA"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#googtrans(en|ja)" class="lang-es lang-select" data-lang="ja"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/google-translate/flag-japan.png" alt="JAPAN"></a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
     new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');
   }

   function triggerHtmlEvent(element, eventName) {
     var event;
     if (document.createEvent) {
       event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
       event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
       element.dispatchEvent(event);
     } else {
       event = document.createEventObject();
       event.eventType = eventName;
       element.fireEvent('on' + event.eventType, event);
     }
   }

   jQuery('.lang-select').click(function() {
     var theLang = jQuery(this).attr('data-lang');
     jQuery('.goog-te-combo').val(theLang);

     //alert(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
     window.location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
     location.reload();

   });
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Here is the CSS code:

````
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}
.lang-select {

  justify-content: center;

}
.ct-topbar {
  text-align: right;
  background: #eee;
}
.ct-topbar__list {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ct-language__dropdown{
    padding-top: 8px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    left: -3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0;
  z-index:200;
}
.ct-language__dropdown li{
    background: #222;
    padding: 5px;
}
.ct-language__dropdown li a{
    display: block;
}
.ct-language__dropdown li:first-child{
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.ct-language__dropdown li:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.ct-language__dropdown li:hover{
    background: #444;
}
.ct-language__dropdown:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 8px;
    height: 0;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right-width: 8px;
    border-left-width: 8px;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
}
.ct-language{
    position: relative;
  background: #00aced;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.ct-language:hover .ct-language__dropdown{
    max-height: 200px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.list-unstyled {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}```
````

Comment: try using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align your image with the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `.ct-language__dropdown li`. Like this:

```
.ct-language__dropdown li {
  background: #222;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
```

[Check it in action on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xck816g/1/)